# Removing html with jquery & and removing container if class exists in any element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-injection

I am working with a list of people. *"Friends"* and *"Not Friends"*

Each container represents a person. If the person is my *friend* it will have a button that says *"remove friend"* if the person is *not a friend*; it will have a button that says *"add friend"*

Each person container contains both the "Remove Friend" and "Add Friend" *buttons*. If the person is a friend the *"remove friend"* button will have an addition class of *"hidden-element"* and if the person is not my friend the "*add friend*" button will have the same class of *"hidden-element"*

**Goal:** Only show people who are not my friends.

**Attempt:**

For the .hidden-element class I want to remove the html completely. (not just hide its display). To accomplish that i used `$('.hidden-element').remove();` which i think removes all buttons with the class of ".hidden-element" from the html?

To identify which person is a friend and which person is not a friend. I removed all elements with the class of "*.hidden-element*" Leaving only the visible button left in the "*.person*" container. To accomplish that i used `$('.hidden-element').remove();` which i think removes all buttons with the class of ".hidden-element" from the html.

Now i want to remove all elements with the class of ".person" **ONLY IF** they contain *anywhere* inside them, an element with the class of ".remove-friend"

so i tried this:

```
if($('.person').find('.remove-friend').length) {
            $( '.person' ).remove();
}
```

Which just removed ALL elements with the class of "*.person*" which is not what I want. Because I want ONLY people who are NOT FRIENDS to show on the front-end

---

## HERE IS A FULL JS FIDDLE


**Change the .remove to .show** in the Jquery to see the html layout for a better understanding.

Comment: Sure you did. But the Close Vote is for "... must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**." (bold emphasis included).

Comment: 4 years later and still a perfectly formatted question despite stackoverflow mods deleting my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do :

```
$('.remove-friend').parents('.person').remove()
```

here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nwop13L9/40/

But as @CalvinNunes said -> juste do `$('.friend').remove();`

even simpler

Comment: I would use `closest` in this case rather than `parents`.  But nice catch flipping the logic like that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nwop13L9/44/   What do you mean? @Patrick

Comment: Check this js fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/9kLnvyqm/59/ The other one i made was just for this example. But when i try to apply it here https://jsfiddle.net/9kLnvyqm/59/  "which is essentially the same" it doesnt work.

Comment: Because all container have `FriendRequestOutgoing` class

Comment: Yes as did all all containers having the ".remove-friend" class in the original example

Comment: Juste try : `$('.FriendRequestOutgoing:not(.hidden_elem)').parents('.clearfix._60rh._gse').remove()` for example (+ a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9kLnvyqm/64/)

Comment: Oh yeah, you just confused hidden_elem and hidden-elem

https://jsfiddle.net/9kLnvyqm/68/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with

```
$('.person').each(function(index, element) {
    if($(element).find('.remove-friend').length) {
        $(element).remove(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working for me, can u add an updated jsfiddle link? Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: There was just a parenthesis missing. Fixed that:https://jsfiddle.net/nwop13L9/51/